# Are these two sets always coincide after a translation or scaling?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, inequalities, geometric-measure-theory

I get stuck with the following problem, which I think is related to sum-product estimate. Here is the problem.

> **Problem** 
>   Given two sets $A, B\subset \mathbb R^n$, and a sires of positive number $\delta_1>\delta_2>...>\delta_n>...>0$, now $\forall n\in \mathbb N^*$, there is a cover of $A$ by a group of balls with radius equals $\delta_n$, i.e. $A=\cup_{i\in I_n}B_{\delta_n}(x_i)$
>   and $B$ could covered by the same group of balls but after a transform at the same time, i.e. $B=\cup_{i\in I_n}\hat B_{\delta_n}(x_i)$
>    where for every $i\in I_n$ $\hat B_{\delta_n}(x_i)$ is come from a translation with constant $d$ of $B_{\delta_n}(x_i)$, i.e $$\hat B_{\delta_n}(x_i)=B_{\delta_n}(x_i+d_i),\ d_i\in D_n.$$
>     or come from the scaling with constant $\lambda$, i.e. $$\hat B_{\delta_n}(x_i)=B_{\delta_n}(\lambda_i x_i),\ \lambda_i\in \Lambda_n.$$
>   And $\exists 0<c<1$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb N^*$, $$\max \{|D_n|,|\Lambda_n|\}<|I_n|^c.$$ Then $B$ should equal to a translation of $A$ or a scaling of $A$, i.e.
>   $$B=A+d, \ or\  B=\lambda A.$$

Now I try to explain how I find this problem, when I try to find a proof of the classical result of sum-product estimate, i.e.

> **Theorem(Erdos-Szemeradi)**
>   $\exists c>0$ such that $\forall A$ is finite set of $\mathbb R$, we have the following estimate:
>   $$|A+A|+|A\cdot A|\geq |A|^{1+c}.$$

This estimate could be understood in following way, there is two foliation of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$, induce by the following two map, the first one is given by addition,
$$A: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$(x,y)\longrightarrow x+y$$
The second one is given by multiplication,
$$M: \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$$
$$(x,y)\longrightarrow x\cdot y$$
Then $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R=\cup_{s\in \mathbb R}A(s)=\cup_{s\in \mathbb R}M(s)$, where $A(s)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,x+y=s\}$,$M(s)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,x\cdot y=s\}$.

Then we look at the fiber of $A\times A$, there is a order of $A\times A$ induce by the order $y_1<y_2<...<y_w$, where $A=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_w\}$. And we define the fibers as $l_1,...,l_{2w-1}$, 
$$l_i=\{(y_p,y_q)| \ p+q=i, 1\leq p,q\leq w\}$$ 
then if the problem have a satisfied answer, take $A=l_i, B=l_{i+1}$ for typical $i\in \{1,2,...,2w-2\}$ we can say some thing for the original inequality, at least for $A$ such that $|A|$ is not very small, in this case we can choose a lot of scale to applicate the result in Problem, but there need a effective version of the problem I think.

I appreciate to any helpful comments and answer, thank you!